# Confusion with the group theory notation

Tags: metric-tensor, group-theory, notation

I know for a group $O(N)$, $N$ is the dimensionality of the matrix corresponding to the transformation, but then for Lorentz transformation we say its $O(3,1)$ while the dimensions of transformation matrix is $4\times 4$. So my question is what these numbers stand for? in case of $O(3,1)$ I know that 3 is for three rotations and 1 is for the boost but in general what do they indicate? for example if we have a group $SU(2,2)$ what do 2 and 2 stand for? And what are the dimensions of the matrix that correspond to this representation?

Comment: In $O(3,1)$, the metric is $(1,1,1,-1)$ (or equivalently $(-1,-1,-1,1)$.  In $SU(2,2)$ it is $(1,1,-1,-1)$.  In general, for $SU(p,q)$ the metric will be diagonal and contain $+1$ $p$ times and $-1$ $q$ times.  Note that neither $O(3,1)$ nor $SU(2,2)$ are compact so the $4\times 4$ realization of the group as matrices will not be unitary.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: why not flesh that out into an answer?

Comment: @KyleKanos Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $O(3,1)$, the metric is $(1,1,1,-1)$ (or equivalently $(-1,-1,-1,1)$.) 
 Thus $O(3,1)$ matrices preserve the length of vectors, with length defined by
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2\, ,
$$
for the metric $(1,1,1,-1)$ (with obvious applications to special relativity).

In $SU(2,2)$ the metric is $(1,1,-1,-1)$ and transformations will preserve the (complex) inner product
$$
xx^*+yy^*-zz^*-tt^*\, .
$$

In general, for $SU(p,q)$ the metric will be diagonal and contain $+1$ $p$ times and $-1$ $q$ times, and will preserve the length of vectors defined by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^p x_kx^*_k - \sum_{s=p+1}^{p+q} x_sx_s^*\, .
$$

Note that neither $O(3,1)$ nor $SU(2,2)$ are compact so the $4\times 4$ realization of the group as matrices will not be unitary.  The most obvious example of this observation is the boost matrix
$$
L(\beta)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\cosh(\beta)&0&0&\sinh(\beta)\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
\sinh(\beta)&0&0&\cosh(\beta)\end{array}\right)
$$
acting on the vector $(t,x,y,z)$, with $\beta$ is the rapidity parameter.  Clearly here $L^{\dagger}(\beta)=L(\beta)\ne L(-\beta)$, with the latter being the inverse of $L(\beta)$.